# How to not handle pointer events in a Component derivate

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to have a Container instance to handle pointer events. However when I start placing components in this container those steal the pointer events even if I set setIgnorePointerEvents(true) on those components like Label instances.

I assume it is not possible to create Component derivates that don't handle pointer events. Is that correct or how is it done?

Also it seems to be a bad idea to delegate pointer events to their parent containers since that would lead to recursion.

Are there best practices regarding handling of pointer events?

Comment: Maybe your question would be clearer if you explain your use case. However... I guess that you want something a like a `Container` plus a `leader Component` that handles all pointer events. It's possible and easy. The documentation is here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html#lead-component-section

Comment: I want to create a “list” of Container elements which shall handle manual sorting by drag and drop, insertion and deletion of elements, tapping on elements - all that to be reused various times with arbitrary components in the Container elements. Therefore I want the Container elements to handle most of the pointer events

Comment: So the question is really - how to not handle pointer events in a Component derivate in order to leave those pointer events to the parent Container

Answer (score 1):

Set the container to focusable or just place an invisible focusable component on top of the container in a layered layout and grab all events there. You can then decide who receives an event by invoking the pointer events on that component manually.

Comment: OK, I can do that. But that does not answer the question. Is there a way to not handle pointer events in a Component derivate?

Comment: An wouldn’t it be better if the Component decided whether to handle a pointer event instead of it’s Container

Comment: Also I can think of use cases where the Component AND it’s Container should react to the same pointer event

Comment: For example dragging. It would be ideal to decide whether vertical dragging or horizontal dragging is meant by deciding about that only after the drag location differs from the tap location by a certain threshold - before it would be ideal if both the Component and it’s Container handled the same dragging events. I think that works with nested Containers which are scrolling in different axes. I’d like that to work for my custom components, too. And I think that should work with components like Switch out of the box.

Comment: @StefanEder What about evt.consume inside a pointerPressedListener, a PointerDraggedListener and a PointerReleasedListener? Consuming the pointer event prevents that it can propagate to the childs components.

Comment: @StefanEder Components propagate events top to bottom in Codename One. It's a decision that was made 12 years ago and won't change.

Comment: All I can see is that Form calls the pointer events of the deepest child directly. I cannot retrace this propagation thing at all. 
So - there is no answer to "How not to handle pointer events in a Component derivate"

Comment: I think it needs to be possible to add a component or a compound component to an arbitrary Container without knowing about it, without needing about to know it's behaviour and not breaking anything

Comment: Those are possible, you have use cases and expectations that we don't share. We've been through these discussions multiple times and they serve no purpose by now. We won't rewrite everything and break everything because you want to write something in a specific way. We have other priorities.